# ComboBox. Is there a way to display a selected value that isn't in the list

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Say I have a ComboBox which has an array of doubles as the ItemsSource.  In that array are the numbers "1.0" and "2.5".  If I change the SelectedValue to "3.0" the ComboBox goes blank. How do I get the ComboBox to display "3.0" without having to add it to the list of possible values that would appear in the drop-down box?

I guess what I'm really asking is do I need some sort of customised combobox to display an item that is not in the drop down list?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The ComboBox doesn't display whatever I bind to Text even if I do something simple like Text="cheese".

Comment: How can you set the selectedvalue to something that isn't in the list of options? That doesn't make sense. Add it to the list of possible values first and then change it.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is do I need some sort of customised combobox to display an item that is not in the drop down list?

Comment: Yes. That isn't what the combobox is for. Its purpose is to show a selected value from a range of possible values.

Comment: Why do you need to have some value if it isn't part of the list of options?

Comment: Because I have limited screen real estate so my drop down box serves as an output as well as an input.

Comment: I think you need to sit back and think about what you are asking and why you need to do it before trying to hack it.

Comment: Bind `Text` DP and set `IsEditable` to true if you want to have other values apart from values in ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* (but not best) way to achieve your requirements (gathered from the comments because you didn't explain them properly in your question) is to add a `TextBlock` *in front of* your `ComboBox`:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Output} Visibility="{Binding IsOutputVisible, Converter=
        {StaticResource BooleanToVisbilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

You could then add a `bool IsOutputVisible` property to make it visible or hide it whenever you need to... you'd need to use a `BooleanToVisbilityConverter` to make this work.